# Differnt way of uninstalling device admin app for different phones

Tags: android, device-admin

I have added my app as device admin. Now when uninstalling the app, For Moto G I get a screen which ask me to "Manage Device Administrators". But for Samsung S6, it just disables the "Ok" button of App uninstall alert box. Can anyone tell me the reason why it is so. And if i need to do anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason each is different is because each OEM skins their devices differently. So each will be slightly different but overall still the same. If you are trying to uninstall the app on your Samsung device, you should be able to go into "Settings > Security > Device Admins" and disable it from in there before uninstalling.

Comment: Thank you @Sean Behan for your answer. But i just wanted to know if there is way to let the user know about disabling the device admin before uninstalling my app.

Comment: oh I see, I'm not sure. you should be able to check if the package uninstaller is uninstalling an package with the id of yours, and then show a notification to open security settings? I'm not sure if that's very helpful, maybe someone else can help answer you.